# Как переставить элементы в массиве

Tags: c, массивы

Нужно с клавиатуры задать массив, а затем переставить в нём элементы так, чтобы сначала расположились все неотрицательные, а затем все отрицательные. Порядок чисел должен быть сохранён прежним.
У меня есть код, он практически работает, но только переставляет местами положительные элементы, изменяя их порядок. Помогите найти ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

```
printf("Nacalniy massiv: \n"); /*Вывод на экран начального массива*/
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%f\n", a[i]);

for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = n-1; j > 0; j--)
    {

        if (a[j] >= 0)
        {
            int k = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            a[j - 1] = k;
        }
    }
}
printf("\nNoviy massiv: \n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    printf("%f\n", a[i]);
}
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Исправьте условие

```
if(a[j]>=0 && a[j-1]<0)
```

У вас перестановка должна быть только если встретились положительный и отрицательный одновременно.